# Combine whole word substitution with Regex character in Python

Tags: python, regex, perl

So i have a dictionary like this :

```
corrections = {'L.C.M.':'LCM','L.C.M':'LCM'}
sometext = 'L.C.M is cool but L.C.M. is not L.C.Mwhichshouldnotchange'
expected = 'LCM is cool but LCM is not L.C.Mwhichshouldnotchange'
```

I need to do replace the 1st and 2nd to LCM, so i write this code

```
for abbr,replace in corrections.items():
    pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(abbr) + r'\b'
    sometext = re.sub(pattern, replace, sometext)
```

This code is somewhat working but

```
L.C.M. -> (Apply 1st replacement) -> LCM. (which is wrong)
L.C.M. -> (Apply 2nd replacement) -> LCM  (right)
```

I need a fool proof  replacement code because i have a big list of abbreviations to substitute

Comment: try with this pattern `pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(abbr) + r'(?=\s)'`

Answer (score 0):

A importance thing is the order of `corrections.items()`. In this case `corrections.items()` yield `L.C.M` then `L.C.M.`, which is not desiarable order. My solution is to check items of `corrections` with reverse dictionary order. The reverse dictionary order yield `L.C.M.` then `L.C.M`. To do this, replace

```
for abbr,replace in corrections.items():
```

with

```
rev_dict_items = sorted(list(corrections.items()))
rev_dict_items.reverse()
for abbr,replace in rev_dict_items:
```

Comment: I tried both the solution, your worked too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here in matching `L.C.M.` since it is followed by a dot and you are also applying word boundary using `\b`. Word boundary won't match the last dot `(.)` because it is not followed by any alphanumeric character.

If you want to make sure that the string you want to match is not followed by a non-whitespace character, you could do it like following:

[**`\b(L\.C\.M\.)(?!\S)`**](https://regex101.com/r/nZ5cK6/1)

`(?!\S)` here will make sure that your matching string is not followed by non-whitespace character. So it will match if there is a space afterwards or if it is the end of the string.

[**IDEONE DEMO**](https://ideone.com/0bjiDi)